# Prove that natural Nos are complete

Tags: calculus

My trial.

Let $A$ be a non empty subset of $N$ that has an upper bound.Define B={$n\in N$: $n$ is an upper bound of $A$}.By the well-ordering property $B$ has a minimal element,call it $m$.

We claim $m$= sup$A$ and $m\in A$. Either $m=0$ or $m>0$
If $m-0$ then $0$ is an upper bound of $A$ by definition of m,in whicn case $A$={$0$},so that the proof is complete.
If $m>0$ we can write $m=k+1$ for some integer $k\in N$.

By definition $m$ is an upper bound of $A$ ,it remains to show that $m\in A$.

Suppose otherwise that $\neg(m\in A)$,as $m$ is an upper bound for $A$,we have $x\leq m$ for all $x\in A$.

But since we assumed $\neg(m\in A)$ we have $x<m$ for all $x\in A$.

Writting $m=k+1$ we get $x<k+1$ and so $x\leq k$ for all $x\in A$ .

It follows that $k$ is an upper bound of $A$ and $k<m$ contradicting minimality of $m$.

Thus we conclude that $m\in A$

Is that proof correct??

Answer (score 2):

It’s basically correct, but you’re showing more than just completeness. Completeness requires only that there *be* a supremum: it does not require that the supremum belong to the set. Thus, when you observe that the well-ordering property ensures that the set of upper bounds for $A$ has a least element, you’ve already shown that $\Bbb N$ is complete. What you’re showing is the stronger statement that each non-empty subset of $\Bbb N$ that has an upper bound not only has a least upper bound, but actually has a maximum element.

Comment: on what grounds can you so categorically,say that my proof is basically correct??

Comment: @chris: Knowledge of the subject.

Comment: HOW do you know that uour knowledge of the subject is correct and complete ??